# How to detect batch logon disabled on RegisterTaskDefinition

Tags: c#

I use Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler for creating new Task in Windows Scheduler.

Code like this:

```
using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
{
    // ...
    ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(
        taskName, td, TaskCreation.Create, userId, password,
        TaskLogonType.Password);
}
```

My problem that I cant detect situation when userId has no rights for batch logon.

In Windows API this situation detected by HRESULT from RegisterTaskDefinition as SCHED_S_BATCH_LOGON_PROBLEM (0x0004131C).

But in c# lib this result is hidden and no exception thrown.

Comment: What *"c# lib"*? [This](https://github.com/dahall/taskscheduler)?

Comment: Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler